# Galois Theory: Quartic and Klein 4 group

Tags: polynomials, permutations, galois-theory, roots

I'm studying Galois Theory on my own and already understand the correspondence between field automorphisms and subgroups of the permutation group. However, I am trying to approach it more from the historical point of view, that is in the language used by Lagrange and am having trouble finding the role of normal subgroups.

Suppose $f$ is a quartic. The strategy is to find a polynomial on the four roots $r_1,r_2,r_3,r_4$ that takes $m < deg(f)$ under the permutation of roots. These $m$ values can be obtained by solving a polynomial of lower degree and then using them recover the original roots.

What I don't understand is the following: we can use the polynomial $r_1r_2+r_3r_4$, which takes $3$ values under root permutations. A cubic is solved and then these $3$ values can be used to find $r_1,r_2,r_3,r_4$. I've seen some notes online that say that the subgroup of permutations that fix this polynomial is the Klein 4 group. But the group that fixes the polynomial is $\{I,(12),(34),(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23),(1423),(1324)\}$, which is not the Klein 4 group, not even a normal subgroup.

Perhaps I am mistaken to expect the normal subgroup to show up here or I misunderstood what I read online. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Let $M = \mathbf{Q}(r_1,r_2,r_3,r_4)$, so $G = \mathrm{Gal}(M/\mathbf{Q}) \hookrightarrow S_4$. The cubic resolvent has roots $\theta_1 = r_1 r_2 + r_3 r_4$, $\theta_2 = r_1 r_3 + r_2 r_4$, and $\theta_3 = r_1 r_4 + r_2 r_3$. As you correctly observe, $\theta_1$ is fixed by a copy of the Dihedral group $D_8$ of order $8$ in $S_4$, so $\mathrm{Gal}(M/\mathbf{Q}(\theta_1))$ is the intersection of $G$ with this copy of $D_8$.

Comment: To see the Klein $4$-group, however (which is normal in $S_4$), you want to take the base field to be Galois. So you should let $K = \mathbf{Q}(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3)$ be the splitting field of the cubic resolvent. Then you will see that the Galois group $\mathrm{Gal}(M/K)$ is the intersection of the three copies of $D_8$, and will be equal to the (intersection of $G$ with the) Klein $4$-group.